# RDP to a server behind load balancer - allow per original source IP

Tags: windows, firewall, ip, rdp

I have some Windows 2016 servers that are located behind a load balancer.  I don't have any control over the load balancer other than being able to connect to servers via it. This whole set up is in the cloud. I need to enable RDP connection on the windows servers - to allow connections for management/monitoring/etc. As I don't have any control over the load balancer, I cannot put any security/firewall/etc. rules on it. If I allow RDP connections to the servers, that means that anybody from anywhere can RDP onto them (provided they have credentials, of course, but that doesn't help in case of any 0-day in RDP protocol for example).

When I RDP onto these servers, I have to specify a load balancer cookie indicating which server I'm connecting to - that's the only control I have.

I can set up firewall rules on the servers themselves to only allow RDP connection from certain IP addresses.  But when I enable RDP and connect to the server, the RDP session lists the remote address as the internal IP of the load balancer (i.e. 10.x.x.x) .

So, is there any way I can restrict RDP on servers to specific external IP addresses?

Comment: Generally you don't route management traffic over a load balancer . Instead you provide an independent means of management access to your servers. (Typically you would set up a VPN server for example and once the VPN connection is established you can access the internal IP-address of the servers and connect with RDP to the servers, by-passing the loadbalancer completely.)

Comment: Off topic: Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault. As HermanB said - you do NOT do this routing setup, whoever set that up made a policy without thinking about the consequences. NOT reasonable management practices. Point them to this link - they should have provided you i.e. with a VPN access that you can use to then access the servers behind the load balancer.

Comment: @HermanB thanks for your comment - and I understand this.  Yet I am stuck with the existing setup for the foreseeable future and need to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming typical configurations for the load balancer and overall network, no.  You will need to implement such security measures on the load balancer.